# How can I stop Ubuntu (using KDE) from saving my last sessions after a shut down?

Tags: kde, shutdown

The question might be weirdly worded but I don't know how else to describe it.

I am using Ubuntu with KDE as a display manager and Whenever I shut down my system via the shut down button a few windows will instantly be open whenever I start my PC again. Despite being open I still have to close them since the windows are will be filled solid black and display a cog in the middle. It'll usually be something like Firefox, Thunderbird, KSnip and Discord.

It's mildly annoying to be honest and I would like to know what causes this and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session, and then, change the settings in "On Login" section, the options are:

- Restore previous session (default, and the cause of your headache).
- Restore manually saved session (only if you save session before shutdown).
- Start with an empty session (the best for your wishes).

You can check more settings about session management in the [KDE UserBase Wiki](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Desktop_Session).